# Non Financial Reward

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing about how a business can make a change that benefits the community and increases their profits, the line I am stuck on is

'...and rewarding both _______ and financially'

What word can I use to fill in the blank.

Comment: The parallel between ___ (let's say, *socially*, for now) and *financially* makes it look like both items are benefits for the company. If you're referring to the benefits flowing to different parties (the 'community' and the 'business'), try changing the structure - e.g. *to the community's benefit and the business's profit*.

Comment: I think the way you mention it splits the benefits too harshly, I want to convey that the social benefits are important to the business as well.

Comment: Hmm, can you describe the view from the perspective of the business? How (or perhaps *what*) do they benefit when the community benefits? This isn't a rhetorical question; if you can describe the benefit to the business, it would go a long way towards filling that blank in a satisfying manner.

Comment: When we talk about the financial benefit that is more tangible, whereas what the blank represents is the intangible. For example the reputation of the business increases, the benefits affect the staff by improving morale and making them feel better for helping the community. Socially does seem like a good fit, but only like 90%.

Comment: "I want to convey that the social benefits are important to the business as well." Then what is wrong with just using **socially** in the sentence? (Why don't you like that word?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best approach here would be to reword the sentence to achieve the cadence and emphasis that you really want, and to use concrete nouns in place of abstract adverbs. For example:

- rewarding *to the shareholders* and *to the community as a whole*.

IMHO, you should listen to what your difficulty in finding a word is actually telling you.  It looks to me like you have chosen a strong rhythmic pattern and are now looking for a set of soft beats and soft syllables that will lead up to a strongly empahsized *financially*.

However, if you keep your present structure, it almost doesn’t matter what word you use in the *_____ and financially* position, since its impact will be diminished by the listener’s perception of its secondary role. This is why *socially* might not be such a good choice, especially if you think that the benefits to the community are important.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than “financially” and (something else),
consider “tangibly” and “intangibly”:

> #### *tangible:*
>
> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/tangible):
>
>     Clear and definite; real.
>     *‘the emphasis is now on tangible results’*
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/tangible):
>
>     important and noticeable
>     *The plan will bring tangible economic benefits to the area.*

> #### *intangible:*
>
> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/intangible):
>
>   - Unable to be touched or grasped; not having physical presence.
>       *‘my companions do not care about cyberspace or anything else so intangible’*
>
>     Difficult or impossible to define or understand; vague and abstract.
>       *‘the rose symbolized something intangible about their relationship’*
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/intangible):
>
>     not able to be touched or measured, and difficult to describe or explain
>     *She has that intangible quality
>       that a player must possess to be a champion.*